# C++11 : Why is the copy ctor being called here?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Consider the code below running C++11. If I understand move semantics correctly, the copy constructor should not be called. But it is. Can someone explain why?

```
template<class D>
struct traced
{
public:
  traced() = default;
  traced(traced const&) { std::cout << typeid(D).name() << " copy ctor\n"; }

protected:
  ~traced() = default;
};


class A : public traced<A>{
public:
  A(int x) : x_(x) {}
private:
  int x_;
};

int main() {
  // I thought the following two are equivalent. Apparently not.
  aList.push_back(A(6)); // Prints out ".. copy ctor" ..
  aList.emplace_back(6); // Does not print out " ... copy ctor"
}
```

Comment: You explicitly declared a copy ctor for `traced` so it has no move ctor.

Comment: Well, why does it work in the case of emplace_back then? Shouldn't traced's copy ctor be called even in that case?

Comment: emplace_back is using the default constructor. It does not copy, that's the point of emplace_back.

Comment: [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) and [`Implicitly-declared move constructor`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Implicitly-declared_move_constructor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
aList.push_back(A(6));
```

This constructs a temporary `A` and moves it into the container. The implicitly generated move constructor of `A` is called, which needs to construct the base `traced<A>` from the base subobject of the temporary. However, `trace` explicitly declares a copy constructor, so it doesn't have move constructor by default, and `A`'s move constructor nonetheless needs to perform a copy for its base class subobject.

```
aList.emplace_back(6);
```

This constructs an `A` directly into the container. No copy or move of any sort is involved.

Comment: :S My gcc defines push_back as:  `push_back(T&& obj)`.. It's has the same exact signature as `emplace_back`.  Using mingw-builds-64 4.8.1 posix-threads seh. But good explanation.

Comment: @Brandon You must be using a very odd version of gcc if `emplace_back` has that signature.

Comment: @TC; http://i.imgur.com/POotrLp.png I checked Visual Studio 2013. Same thing. Both of them have it like that. I guess it's not the "exact" same "signature" as `emplace_back`.. but it does use `emplace_back`. It might as well be the same signature.

Comment: @Brandon Ah, `emplace_back` is variadic; `push_back` is not. It constructs the object in place, passing to the constructor whatever arguments you passed to it. So if you do `emplace_back(A(6))` it will move (it constructs in-place passing the temporary `A` to the constructor - which is a move), but `emplace_back(6)` doesn't move - it constructs in-place passing `6` to the constructor directly.